# real version of jdk used by spring boot maven plugin

Tags: spring-boot, maven, java-11

i use spring boot maven plugin and i have an issue

how to know exact jdk is used to **build project** when i launch this command ?

```
    mvn spring-boot:run
```

in fact, when i do

```
    mvn clean package
```

the result is different (first fails, second successes)
but i don't know which jdk is used.
In fact, when i do

```
   mvn -V spring-boot:run
```

it gives me jdk used to run, and not jdk used to build.

thanks

Comment: The first must fail...the second builds all things needed... calling `mvn --version` will print the information which JDK is used to run which is usually the same to build with... There are options if you have the need to run with JDK 8 for example build for JDK 7 (https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-using-toolchains.html)...

Comment: @khmarbaise no, mvn --version does not return jdk used by command mvn spring-boot:run. In fact, changing this jdk does not interfer on result. And it should.

Comment: Where is JAVA_HOME pointing?

Comment: @khmarbaise JAVA_HOME points to a jdk8, and then a jdk11. It should fail on jdk11 but it doesn't. so i suspect mvn spring-boot plugin not to use jdk returned by $JAVA_HOME variable.

Comment: So If you use `mvn clean package` the JDK pointing via JAVA_HOME is used to build the app. `mvn -V spring-boot:run` uses the same but the question is why should it fail with JDK11 ? Please show the error messages etc. which Spring Boot verison you are using...?

Comment: @khmarbaise ok, i try to be more precise. my build in jdk11 should fail because of my code which is not upgraded. It DO fail with command mvn clean package and DO NOT fail with command mvn spring-boot:run. So i suspect mvn spring-boot:run not to switch jdk when i switch $JAVA_HOME to jdk8 versus jdk11 and vice-versa. the verbose command (-V) always say i use jdk11 but it seems to always refer to jdk8 as it never fail. 1) where can i switch to jdk11 for building with springboot plugin 2) how can i check the real version used for building in the console ?

Comment: As I wrote before please add the error message which are produced... it's useless to repeat the parts which are already in the post...

Comment: @khmarbaise there IS NO error message, as it SHOULD FAIL on jdk11 using mvn springboot plugin. My question is : why it DO NOT use jdk11, like it is displayd on verbose mode when i launch : mvn -V spring-boot:run. I want to make plugin fail the build to HAVE SAME BEHAVIOUR as classic command : mvn clean package. So : where can we switch jdk for plugin maven, as switching $JAVA_HOME do not have effect (it has effect with classic command but not with plugin command)